# Data Structure for holding parsed csv Bus route data

Tags: javascript, mysql, csv, web, data-structures

I have a csv file of about 10k rows x 25 columns. The csv contains information of bus routes, stops, etc. I have a select box with all the routes and the user will be able to pick a single route to show on the map, and then they will be able to click on individual stops (another select box) to get a closer look on the map. I am wanting to know what will be the best way to parse and structure to store this information and be able to perform fast queries (**database?**), and how should I store the result of the query (array, json object, dictionary, **data Table?**). I won't need all columns every time, so I will pick the useful columns to make the query a little faster.

Each time a user will select a different route, I will make a query to get all the stops and other relevant information and loop through the data to display it on the map (maybe store results of last 5 queries?). What will be the best way to store this result? Showing the specific stop information won't be too big of a deal since it will be a smaller subset of the already queried results.

Let me know if you need any additional information that will assist with the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Google releasd a public scheme called gtfs which is a transport data structure. You would ideally use a graph data structure. I have found neo4j a good option.

Comment: I am not providing all the transport services/options. Currently I will just provide the routes on a map, specific stop details, and a picture/bus stop rating. Later on, I will provide directions, and other features.

Answer (score 0):

See this github project for an example of how to use a graph database for this purpose:

https://github.com/tguless/neo4j-gtfs